# Falling Marble Sensor

Tags: raspberry-pi, magnetics, hall-effect, magnet

I'm really building a sort of Rube Goldberg machine that students will assemble in order to guide a falling ball down through a series of gates/openings, where I need to detect when they're successful in making it through one of the gates.  My plan is to hook each gate up a Raspberry Pi in some way, though I'm not 100% sure what components I should/could use.

Are there any electrical components/breakout boards/ideas I could use to detect large marbles falling through a gate/pass?  I've been debating on using a phototransistor and some LEDs to detect when the LED light is interrupted, thus signalling the passing of the ball, but I didn't know if there was a better and simpler solution.  Maybe some sort of gate that won't mess with the marble's trajectory?  A light or motion sensor?  Something that can quickly detect the marble's presence?  Some sort of trip wire?

For reference, [here are the magnetic marbles that I'm using](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01L5WAIQC).  I'm using a Pi Zero too.

Comment: If the balls are magnetic, a reed switch is a better bet. It also comes down to how fast the ball moves through the gate/pass so that the reed switch can actually register it followed by the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: bi-polar hall sensor ics. cheap and easy

Comment: IR photogates are very common in student physics labs, typically for timing but you could use them for simple event detection, too.  I recall they worked well for a marble rolling down the central groove of a plastic ruler.  A simple MCU or Arduino-class system is going to be a much better match for this than a raspberry pi.

Comment: This looks like a cross-post of https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/81831/falling-marble-sensor

Comment: It is indeed a cross post, I didn't know which site would be the best place to ask about this

Comment: Oh nice! I like the reed switch idea, that's a new one!  I like the idea too of using the IR photogate, and I think I may ultimately go for that solution in the interest of being cost effective and shock resistant.  Thank you all for the great ideas!